# discord.py wait_for not working in a method

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have 2 separate files in this case, where 1 is for the main file, and another is a file containing functions(not in a Cog). I want to have a user respond to the message that a bot outputs and then the bot will send that message back into the chat.

The issue over here is that the program is not registering a message that a person inputs and I tried using `self.bot` or `client` instead of just bot for the `wait_for` function, but that doesn't work.

Here is my code for my `main.py` file

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from anime import *
from embed import *

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="m.")

TOKEN = "INSERT TOKEN HERE"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Connected to discord")

@bot.command(name="searchanime", help="Seaches through the MAL Database to find an anime. Requires a Title to search")
async def search(ctx, *, query):
  await search_anime(ctx, query)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Here is my code for `anime.py` which is a separate file

```
import discord
import requests

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "2ed26cb89emsh2b7cb079ec42fd9p15290cjsne485ef05078a",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "jikan1.p.rapidapi.com"
}

async def search_anime(ctx, query):
    url = "https://jikan1.p.rapidapi.com/search/anime"
    querystring = {"q": query, "format": "json"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

    response_list  = []
    for i in range(4):
        response_list.append(response["results"][i])

    await ctx.send("Message 'm.(desired number)' without the parenthesis to select the anime you are looking for from this list")
    for i in range(len(response_list)):
        await ctx.send(f"{i+1}) {response_list[i]['title']}")
    
    try:
        msg = await bot.wait_for("message")
        if msg:
            await ctx.send(msg.content)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Cancelling due to timeout")
```

Comment: You've not declared the "bot" variable in anime.py, but only in the main.py.
You can define that function in the main.py, it will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bot is simply not defined in your `anime.py`, you can pass it as a parameter to the function.

```py
await search_anime(bot, ctx, query)
```

```py
async def search_anime(bot, ctx, query)
   #other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked! As a followup, would it be more efficient to simply create a cog so that I wouldn't have to pass so many parameters?

Comment: cogs were introduced for this very same purpose.